# Is my timeline visible to the secret group that I have joined?

Tags: facebook-groups, facebook-timeline

Can the members of a secret group that I have joined see my personal timeline posts?

Answer (score 2):

Unless you've posted to your timeline as Public, your membership to a group doesn't influence who sees your timeline posts(unless you've added them as a friend).